# Datetime.now issue on hosted server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, hosting

I have hosted my website on a server which is located in US, whereas the users are currently based in India, and this website will potentially have users across the globe.
The problem is that, DateTime.Now always considers server's datetime and so it is showing dates which is wrong according to client.
This site is developed using MVC 4 and .NET Framework 4.0. 
What could be the best possible solution of such issue?

Comment: You can use UTC time, but I'm not sure it will be comfortable for humans :)

Comment: I will also need to do calculations based on Datetime.UtcNow and client's location. So I think that's not an easy/ accurate option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to use the [DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx). Then you can can, when you render your results, to add the extra hours base on your local area, or the area of the user.

And its faster than the `DateTime.Now` because the `now` call the UtcNow, and add extra code to convert it to local time base on computer/server local settings.

In general the UtcNow is the one that you must use to log everything, its independent time, meaning that is the same across all computers. Then when you render results you can change them base on user's local time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone property.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx for more details.